# How do I disable a button if there are ng-messages shown in angularjs 1.x?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to disable the button unless all conditions for the input are met. Is it possible? For example if the field is filled with a valid input, the button should be enabled.

```
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
                ng-model="main.name"
                ng-minlength="5"
                ng-maxlength="10"
                ng-pattern='/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/'
                required>

            <div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">enter a name </div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">must be longer than 5</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">cannot exceed 10 characters</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">must contain a combination of characters and numbers</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$valid` flag on form field. Over here you can use `userForm.name.$invalid`

```
<button type="submit" 
  ng-disabled="userForm.name.$invalid" 
  class="btn btn-danger">
   Submit
</button>
```

**OR**

If form is going to have single field, then use form validity `userForm.$valid`

```
ng-disabled="userForm.$valid"
```

Comment: Thank you. that's what I exactly wanted!